# TkinterでJPGE画像が表示されない

Tags: python, tkinter

#### 困っていること

TkinterでJPEG画像が表示されません。
png画像やico画像や認識されるのですがjpegだけが無理です。

しっかりpillowをインストールした上でコードを実行しているのですが上手くいきません。コードもエラーなど出ていません。

#### 試したこと

PCの再起動
パスが合っているかの確認

#### 実際のコード

```
# インポート
import tkinter
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

# ウィンドウの作成
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title('Image practice!')
root.iconbitmap('icon.ico')
root.geometry('800x600')
root.resizable(0, 0)

# 画像の配置
image_1 = tkinter.PhotoImage(file='sukahu.png')
label_1 = tkinter.Label(root, image=image_1)
label_1.pack()

button_1 = tkinter.Button(root, image=image_1)
button_1.pack()

image_by_pillow = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('2.jpg'))
label_2 = tkinter.Label(root, image=image_by_pillow)
label_2.pack()

# ウィンドウのループ処理
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: こちらの記事を試してみては？ [【もう間違えない!?】PythonのTkinterを用いて画像を表示する方法](https://kuroro.blog/python/Z7k1LSyDyiDHtD5UCjmG/)

Comment: 記事のコードをコピペして画像ファイルの名前だけ変更し実行したのですが、やっぱり画像が表示されませんでした。

コードの問題ではないっぽいです。どうすればよいのでしょうか

Comment: 環境やPythonやPillowの版数を確認してみるとか、jpegのファイルを色々変えて試してみるとかしてみては？ windows 10でのpython 3.11.1とpillow 9.3.0では出来ました。

Comment: 初心者なもので版数の確認の方法がわかりません。JPEGのファイルを色々変えるのは試しましたが無理でした。無知で申し訳ありません。お願いします

Comment: 普通にインストールされているものならスタートメニューに`Python 3.XX`というのが登録されているはずです。その`3.XX`が版数です。もう少し細かく調べるには、そのメニューの中の2つ目を選択して起動すればPythonインタプリタのコマンドプロンプトが動いて最初に細かい版数を表示するでしょう。ちなみにAnaconda/PyCharmとかVSCodeのPython拡張機能とかのIDE/開発環境を使っていたら、確認方法は変わるかもしれません。そうした情報も追記してみてください。なお、以前の質問に`OneDrive`を使っているとか、フォルダ名に全角文字を使われているようですが、それらが影響しているかもしれません。PCのローカルなドライブで全角文字を含まないフォルダを作成し、その中で確かめてみるのも良いでしょう。

Comment: ローカルドライブは「Dドライブ」ですよね？僕のファイルで見るとDドライブが見当たらないのですがどうすればいいでしょうか？本当に無知で申し訳ありません

Comment: `ローカル`はネットワーク上とかネットワークとの共有でなければ良いので`D:`ドライブではなく`C:`ドライブでも何でもPCにつながっているドライブならOKです。

Comment: それでしたらローカルドライブに移動させても表示されませんね。どうすればいいでしょうか

Answer (score 0):

コメント欄では書きにくいため、回答欄で確認します。
画像が大きすぎて重なっているのかもしれません。

以下のように修正すれば2.jpgが見えるかもしれません。

```
root.geometry('1000x1000')
label_1.pack(side = tkinter.TOP)
button_1.pack(side = tkinter.RIGHT)
label_2.pack(side = tkinter.BOTTOM)
```

Comment: 修正しましたが表示されません。
申し訳ないです

Comment: 13行目のimage_1から18行目のbutton_1まで13行目のimage_1から18行目のbutton_1までコメントアウトしたとき、'2.jpg'は表示されませんか？

Comment: 表示されないですね...

Comment: 残念です。こちらの環境では表示されているのでコードは問題なし、icoとpngが表示されているのでパスの問題でもなしですね。今はノーアイデア、ネタ切れです。

Answer (score 0):

手元の環境でも正しく動作しています。

下記のサンプルコードを実行して画像が表示されるか試してください。(`hoge.jpg`というファイルは上書きされますのでご注意ください)

もし画像が表示される場合は、利用している画像ファイルに問題がある可能性が高いです。
ファイルを変えても表示されずエラーも発生しない点は不可解ながら、画像サイズ(小さすぎたり大きすぎたりしない)や形式(拡張子だけでなく中身のフォーマットもjpegであること)をご確認ください。

もし画像が表示されない場合は、pipを使っているならば`pip install -U pillow`を実行するなどパッケージを最新にして、改善されないかを試してください。

**サンプルコード**

```
import tkinter
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import base64

# 画像ファイル生成
with open("hoge.jpg", "wb") as f:
    f.write(base64.b64decode("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"))

# ウィンドウの作成
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry('200x200')
image_by_pillow = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('hoge.jpg'))
label_2 = tkinter.Label(root, image=image_by_pillow)
label_2.pack()

# ウィンドウのループ処理
root.mainloop()
```